# Why is Illustrator 2021 trying to export contents that are outside the artboard?

Tags: png, artboard

So I'm having a problem I've never had before. I have objects that border the edges of the art board. Illustrator is trying to include the contents of those objects that are outside of the art board when I try to export to PNG.

**This is the document:**
[image]

**This is the file its trying to save:**
[image]

How do I fix this? TIA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you have not checked the box which is "Clip to Artboard"

[image]

Comment: Ahh thanks. I had to reinstall windows recently along with all my adobe apps and I guess I must've just clicked this one time and it always did it for me and i forgot about it. lol

Answer (score 2):

The "Clip to Artboard" checkbox is your ticket!

[image]
[image]